# for-loop can't delete Treeview items (TypeError: must be str, not int)

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

I'm trying to delete every column in the Treeview.
I use for that a for-loop to delete everything, but it only gives me the error:

```
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

My Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class test:

    root = Tk()

    tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
    tree["columns"] = ("A")
    tree.column("#0", width=100)
    tree.heading("#0", text="Values")

    tree.pack()

    tree.insert("", 0, text="Hi", values=("1A"))
    tree.insert("", 0, text="Hi", values=("0A"))

    for x in tree:
        tree.delete(x)

    root.mainloop()

test()
```

Comment: Why do you use a class? You use it like a function, that's really weird.

Comment: This is only a test script. In my main script the Treeview is also included in the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot iterate through the children of a tree with `for x in tree`, you need to use the `get_children(parent)` method. It returns the list of children of the item `parent`. So to clear the tree, you can do

```
for x in tree.get_children(''):
    tree.delete(x)
```

because `''` is the id of the root of the tree.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def clear_tree():
    for x in tree.get_children(''):
        tree.delete(x)

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree["columns"] = ("A")
tree.column("#0", width=100)
tree.heading("#0", text="Values")
tree.pack()
tree.insert("", 0, text="Hi", values=("1A"))
tree.insert("", 0, text="Hi", values=("0A"))

ttk.Button(root, text='Clear', command=clear_tree).pack()
root.mainloop()
```